# How can I import MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, macos, ubuntu

I am not able to import MySQLdb

I tried this:

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

But I am still not being able to import it.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook using parallels.

Diagnosis using comments:

```
pip freeze

abstract-rendering==0.5.1
alabaster==0.7.3
argcomplete==0.8.9
astropy==1.0.3
Babel==1.3
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
bcolz==0.9.0
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
binstar==0.11.0
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.8.0
blz==0.6.2
bokeh==0.9.0
boto==2.38.0
Bottleneck==1.0.0
cdecimal==2.3
certifi==14.5.14
cffi==1.1.0
clyent==0.3.4
colorama==0.3.3
conda==3.14.1
conda-build==1.14.1
conda-env==2.2.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==0.9.1
Cython==0.22.1
cytoolz==0.7.3
datashape==0.4.5
decorator==3.4.2
docutils==0.12
enum34==1.0.4
fastcache==1.0.2
Flask==0.10.1
funcsigs==0.4
gevent==1.0.1
gevent-websocket==0.9.3
greenlet==0.4.7
grin==1.2.1
h5py==2.5.0
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.7
ipython==3.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.0
jedi==0.8.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
jsonschema==2.4.0
llvmlite==0.5.0
lxml==3.4.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.4.3
mistune==0.5.1
mock==1.0.1
multipledispatch==0.4.7
networkx==1.9.1
nltk==3.0.3
nose==1.3.7
numba==0.19.1
numexpr==2.4.3
numpy==1.9.2
odo==0.3.2
openpyxl==1.8.5
pandas==0.16.2
patsy==0.3.0
pep8==1.6.2
Pillow==2.8.2
ply==3.6
psutil==2.2.1
ptyprocess==0.4
py==1.4.27
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.5.1
pyflakes==0.9.2
Pygments==2.0.2
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
pytest==2.7.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.4
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==14.7.0
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.7.0
rope==0.9.4
runipy==0.1.3
scikit-image==0.11.3
scikit-learn==0.16.1
scipy==0.15.1
six==1.9.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.0
sockjs-tornado==1.0.1
Sphinx==1.3.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.7
spyder==2.3.5.2
SQLAlchemy==1.0.5
statsmodels==0.6.1
sympy==0.7.6
tables==3.2.0
terminado==0.5
Theano==0.7.0
toolz==0.7.2
tornado==4.2
ujson==1.33
unicodecsv==0.9.4
Werkzeug==0.10.4
xlrd==0.9.3
XlsxWriter==0.7.3
xlwt==1.0.0
```

Comment: could you please present your "pip freeze" here? Which python package are you trying to import "import MySQLdb"? 
My personal recommendation to give a try PyMySQL.

Comment: Please see edit. Yes, I am trying to use to use MySQLdb. But seems like a lot of people are having the same problem....

Comment: It appears you don't have any mysql lib. You may use either https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should install `MYSQL` environment first.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Then add the following lines to  `.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=/path/to/install/mysql/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/install/mysql/lib/mysql:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then `source .bash_profile`.

Comment: I am getting this error: E: Unable to locate package mysql

Comment: Did you `source .bash_profile`? what's the error message?

Comment: Does anything have to be changed in the /path/to/install etc. or should I just copy-paste those two lines?

Comment: OMG!  Your need to replace `/path/to/install/` to the real path you install `mysql`.

Comment: LOL> I am a noob. WHen I install mysql-client where does it get stored in ubuntu?

Comment: OK, I did it. And now I am getting this error: .bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86748/discussion-between-luoluo-and-maximusdooku).